# How can I get Latitude and Longitude from Facebook User Location?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-login

I managed to recover all the information specified in the code below, but I can't retrieve latitude and longitude of user.location.

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
        NSString *fbUsername = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",user.username];
        NSString *fbNickname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",user.name];
        NSString *fbName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",user.first_name];
        NSString *fbSurname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",user.last_name];
        NSString *fbLocation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",user.location.name];
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but there is absolutely no point in using stringWithFormat: @"%@". Get rid of that whole construct. It just makes the system go to extra work for no reason. Just use code like fbName = user.first_name;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the latitude and longitude of the user try this in the method you posted:

```
NSNumber *userLatitude = user.location.location.latitude;
NSNumber *userLatitude = user.location.location.latitude;
//do whatever you want with the values here
```

Comment: I did as you said, but this NSLog(@"%@",userLatitude); returns (null)

Comment: @Pinturikkio don't know if the value is always provided [here is the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.0/protocol/FBGraphLocation)

Comment: is really strange! None of the values ​​is returned to me! And there is no explanation. Also because the name of the location is returned to me safely

Answer (score 0):

```
     - (void)placePickerViewControllerSelectionDidChange:(FBPlacePickerViewController *)placePicker
 {
// id&#060;
 // FBGraphPlace&#062;
 place = placePicker.selection;


 // we'll use logging to show the simple typed property access to place and location info
 NSLog(@"place=%@, city=%@, state=%@, lat long=%@ %@",
 place.name,
 place.location.city,
 place.location.state,
 place.location.latitude,
 place.location.longitude);
 }
```

Comment: It not work! What should I do? No one can give me a solution? It is possible that I can retrieve the name of the location but not the latitude and longitude (user.location.name)